# Need to calculate the age of horses

Tags: mysql, sql

In SQL, I need to calculate the age of horses that have died, then multiply it by three to get what would be their human age.

There is a column called 'BORN' and a column called 'PASSED', containing only the year they died.

So I need to calculate the age of the horses from the BORN column (year they were born) to the PASSED column (year they passed away) to get there age, then multiply that number by three. Then I just need to list their horse_id, name, and age in human years, but I know how to do that select statement myself.

Comment: if it was born 31/12/2014 and died 01/01/2015 it means his age is 1 year in horses years?

Comment: So far.. all I have is the following. I've read and read the whole year function thingos, but still can't seem to figure this one out.

Select horse_id, name
FROM horse
WHERE died > 0

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Here we will not write your SQL for you - but if you have a go at it, then we can help you get it working. Start by figuring out the kinds of things that code needs to do eg "get the year the horse was born, then..." and write those in the order the computer needs to do them. Then fill in all the bits you know how to do (all the easy bits like "select * from..." while leaving the bits you don't know in just english words... then we can help you convert the english to SQL

Comment: Also - *please* don't put code into the comments... the formatting is truly awful and impossible to read. Edit your question and put it all in there instead,

Comment: This may help you https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: I can figure out how to get there age from there year of birth, just can't figure out how to get there age from BORN to PASSED.

(YEAR(NOW()) - born) That's what i've used to get there age from BORN to NOW.

Comment: what if you subtract born from passed?

Comment: Are you able to help me a bit more with that ? I'm just not sure where and how to write it so it runs.

Comment: You can't even TRY to write `passed - born`, but instead ask cha to show you how???

Comment: If I knew how to do it, I wouldn't be asking on here for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This Code,

```
SELECT horse_id, name, ((PASSED-BORN) * 3) As humanAge FROM horses WHERE PASSED IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want something like this:

```
SELECT horse_id, name, FLOOR((DATEDIFF(PASSED,BORN) / 365) * 3) As humanAge FROM horses WHERE PASSED IS NOT NULL;
```

EDIT: I misinterpreted the question assuming the passed/born columns to be dates. If the columns are 4 digit years as type int, then you may use something like:

```
SELECT horse_id, name, ((PASSED - BORN) * 3) As humanAge FROM horses WHERE PASSED IS NOT NULL;
```

If the column type is varchar then you'll have to change PASSED to CAST(PASSED AS UNSIGNED) and BORN to CAST(BORN AS UNSIGNED)

Comment: Hmm, tried that, but for some reason everything in the 'HUMAN AGE' column comes back as NULL

Comment: Also, if those columns had been dates, you still don't want to use `/365` (or, I've also seen `/365.25` *yikes*) to convert days into years.  Both of those approaches have edge cases that give the wrong result, failing to handle calendar nuances correctly.  Use date/time functions for all date/time math to avoid subtle bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You can also Use following :

```
 SELECT horse_id, name,(DATEDIFF(YEAR,PASSED,BORN) * 3) As humanAge 
 FROM horses WHERE PASSED IS NOT NULL;
```